# Can I get the sizeof (byte-length in C) with Perl?

Tags: c, perl, sizeof

Can I get the sizeof (byte-length in C) with Perl?

```
my $byte_length_in_C_of_int = ...;
```

edit:

[perlpacktut/Integers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Integers):
After the first read I thought "sizeof(...)" and "$Config{...size}" may differ, but after rereading the place I suppose $Config{intsize} gives my the C_int-byte-length.

Comment: perl manage himself memory, i'm not sure you can get this. what is the purpose ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but it would be good to know what you need it for.

If you're building up a data structure to communicate with some other app in binary, your best bet is to go with [pack](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#pack) -- the right combination of formats will let you work with nearly any type in either native or specifically-defined sizes, and it handles things like struct alignment, length-prefixed strings and TLV as well.

For other uses, you might be better looking in [Config](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Config). There are variables in there for the sizes of various types, including `intsize`, `longsize`, `ptrsize`, `doublesize`, `longlongsize` (if `d_longlong` is set), `longdblsize` (if `d_longdbl` is set), `ivtype`/`ivsize`, `nvtype`/`nvsize` (for Perl's internal numeric types), and `byteorder` (so you can figure out endianness).